# Call Grails Controller method without having a view for it

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 3, and am working on a template page, which contains the outline for the rest of the website. I and am attempting to call a method from a controller, by using the following code, as recommended by [the official documentation](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Tags/include.html):

```
<g:include controller="layouts" action="loadUsers" />
```

My controller looks as follows:

```
class LayoutsController {

    def loadUsers() {
        println("we are in here")
    }    

}
```

When the include statement gets executed on my embedded tomcat, I get the following error:

```
[http-nio-8443-exec-4] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet grailsDispatcherServlet threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'loadUsers' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

Ofcourse, the error makes sense, as I do not have that view/gsp page. I want to just simply invoke a method to create some stuff in the backend, not tie it to a gsp page. Is this possible? Basically, a similar approach to JSF where I can execute a public method on a bean.

Comment: are you looking for something like `def loadUsers(){ render 'ok' }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a controller action is invoked, unless the action invokes something like `redirect` or `render`, then a view will be rendered.  That is by design and how controller actions are supposed to behave.  If the view isn't present, then an error occurs.

It isn't clear what you are trying to do but if you are just trying to invoke some logic and you don't want a view that is a little bit of an unusual thing to be doing from a GSP, but you could do it by invoking a custom GSP tag that does whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.  Normally all of that sort of thing is done before the view is rendered (so, before any GSP code is involved).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jeff. While I understand what you are stating, I am confused as to how one would tie the bridge between a gsp and a server side method then. Take for example a dynamic showing of menu items. To me, it makes sense to do some <g:if test="${}"> statements in the template of the website to identify which items in the menu should be present, and which should not. Now instead of tying that to every view/controller, you tell the template to call some method to find out which items should be shown or not. Can you extend on this example to explain what is the right approach?

Comment: I think you can do all of that using your layout, you can have different layouts for different sections if required. Those templates can then carry out the required if logics you talk about - it will still share the main page variables. Failing that wrap the logic of what you seek in a tag lib and call this tag lib where required. I would recommed first method since its the least amount of work @angryip

Comment: @angryip Typically you would do most of that conditional stuff before the view was rendered and then put all of the necessary data in the model that will be made available in the view.  There are cases where it makes sense to defer some of that until view rendering time and for many of those cases, a custom GSP tag would be in order.  For example, you might have a tag called `<foo:renderMenu/>` and the `renderMenu` tag can do whatever it takes to retrieve the necessary data.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown You guys both make good points. I shall try that, and see how far i get. Thanks.